# tuning mtry for party::cforest in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I am currently working on a project that involves using the party::cforest function in R to build a conditional random forest. However, I am facing challenges in determining the appropriate value for the mtry parameter.

I'm considering using either the train function from the caret package or the tuneRF function from the randomForest package to assist in defining the optimal mtry. Would you recommend using either of these functions for a **CONDITIONAL** random forest, or are there alternative approaches that I should consider? There is nothing in party package for tuning mtry

Comment: Hi Kate, welcome to SO. Your question isn't a fit for this site. SO is for specific coding and programming questions and you are asking for advice regarding methods. You are better to ask your question over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). There are heaps of R users at CV and someone should be able to help you. Thanks

Comment: @LTyrone CV deleted similar question and referred me to SO. Actually the question was about the code. And here is the code I used at the end `code` grid <- expand.grid(.mtry=2:ncol(adat)-1)
mod <- train(response ~ ., data = adat,
  method = "cforest",controls = cforest_unbiased(ntree = 500), tuneGrid=grid)
mod$bestTune `code`